# Subset Sum with neighbourhood search - java

Tags: java, algorithm, subset-sum, neighbours

I'm trying to implement Subset Sum problem using the neighbourhood algorithm.
Here's the pseudo-code:

`1. Generate a random solution for the problem and call it S
2. Compute the neighborhood of S and choose S' as the best solution in the neighborhood
3. If S' is better than S then go to step 4, else go to step 6
4. S = S'
5. Go to step 2
6. Return S as the best solution encountered`

Given a set X of 10 elements (+ve and -ve), I have to find a subset of X such that the sum is as close to 0 as possible.

Following the pseudo-code, I've generated a random solution S, but I've encountered some difficulties in building up the neighbourhood S.

How do I compute the neighbourhood of S? What's the neighbourhood of S?

E.g.

X = [x0, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9]

S = [x1, x7, x2, x3]

What's the neighbourhood of S?

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no a unique definition of neighbourhood, it depends from the problem. In your case a good definition could be `all the tuples that have (at most) n different elements from the current solution` where n could be `1, 2 , size - 1` (if you take `n = size` you are considering the whole solution space and speaking of neighbourhood has no more sense).

In your example, taking all solutions that differ of one step from the current one ends un in the following set of solutions:

D = [ [x0, x7, x2, x3], [x4, x7, x2, x3], [x5, x7, x2, x3], [x6, x7, x2, x3], [x8, x7, x2, x3], [x9, x7, x2, x3], [x1, x0, x2, x3], [x1, x4, x2, x3], ... ]

Answer (score 0):

Let's use the example:

S is one solution, let's see how can we generate another one from it:

- We can add another x_i to it creating for example [x1, x2, x3, x7, x8]
- or we can remove a x_i from it creating for example [x2, x3, x7]

Every such solution obtained from S using one of the above operations is a neighbour of S. All of such solutions form the neighbourhood.

Keep in mind that [x1, x3, x2] and [x1, x2, x3] are the same solution as the order of elements doesn't matter.

---

**Formally** every solution is a binary vector v of length 10 consisting of 0's and 1's such as
v[i] == 1 if the corresponding solution contains x_i.

A vector corresponding to the S from example would look like this:
S = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]

Every such vector is a vertex in the graph of solutions. The edge between two such vertices exist if one can be transformed into another using some kind of a simple operation such as those described above.

I hope this helps.